# Design Pattern: Extending a List of Constants

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, polymorphism

I know the title isn't very descriptive but hopefully I can clarify some things with code. I have a class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class Entity {

    protected final static int BASE_STATE_SIZE = 3;
    protected final static int AGE = 0;
    protected final static int X = 1;
    protected final static int Y = 2;

    protected double[] state;

    public Entity () {
        state = new double[getStateSize ()];
        ...
    }

    protected void initDefaultState () {
        state[AGE] = 0;
        state[X] = Math.random () * Renderer.size.width;
        state[Y] = Math.random () * Renderer.size.height;
}

    protected abstract int getStateSize ();

}

public class Critter extends Entity {

    protected final static int STATE_SIZE = Entity.BASE_STATE_SIZE + 1;
    protected final static int HUNGER = Entity.BASE_STATE_SIZE + 0;

    public Critter () {
        ...
    }

    protected void initDefaultState () {
        super.initDefaultState ();
        state[HUNGER] = 0;
    }

    protected int getStateSize () {
        return STATE_SIZE;
    }
}
```

To give a bit more context: entities are just generic objects. Critter is one example of a more specific object. The state of an entity changes frequently throughout its lifetime. In this case, a critter's position, x, y, and hunger change multiple times per second. State values are assigned in the subclass (and occasionally in the main Entity class like age which is updated uniformly for all subclasses). No other outside object should be able to change the state of an entity, only the entity object itself.

This whole design seems a bit fishy to me but I'm not sure how to change it. One alternative would be to make the "state" its own class that is extended by those classes that extend entity. However, with this method each state parameter would require its own function and the parameters could not be iterated through like they can be now. I was wondering if there was a defined design pattern for what I'm doing or if I should just stick with what I have. Thanks!

Comment: Does `state` change during the lifetime of the class? Are you creating Critter only to add or redefine state's data?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Please add some context, more code, other classes that interact with these, what's the meaning of state, Critter, Entity? From the name it may seem you want to use a state pattern, but it might just be a strategy, or something completely different. And knowing what you want and why are important to select a pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I added some more context.

Comment: Is there any special reason why you are using an array to store data (instead of simply having x, y, hunger as attributes of Entity)?

Comment: Many of the values in the state are generated algorithmically (with the same algorithm) so it is convenient to be able to iterate through them.

Comment: It could be that I'm overcomplicating things though

Comment: The State pattern would be a solution if you had several behaviours that would perform differently depending on the state. For example, suppose you had a `speed` and `hunger`, and depending on the terrain (which would be the state), you would have different behaviours (in a desert, hunger would increase, speed would decrease; in a forest, speed would decrease even more, but hunger would decrease). Then you could have a DesertState, and ForestState, inheriting from State. Your object would *have* a State object, and would call its methods. Depending on what the current state is, the behaviour

Comment: would be different (since it would use one state object or the other), and depending on trigger actions you define in your code, you would switch to another state. Each state would implement different `getHunger`, `getSpeed` methods. In your case, it seems that the different attributes vary separately, so they wouldn't really fit in a state. Usually you adopt a design pattern when you have a problem with the current structure. If you read the descriptions, motivations, intents in a design pattern catalog, you might be able to find some description that matches your problem.